# Bring portable generator in through automatic transfer switch

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, code-compliance, generator, transfer-switch

I currently have a portable generator, an inlet, and an interlock on the main panel to backfeed the panel.

I am moving over to an automatic transfer switch with a standby generator. However, as a backup, I am keeping my portable generator and inlet.

I would like to eliminate the interlock and bring the wires from the inlet in through the automatic transfer switch in the same way that the standby generator connects to it, and select which generator I want to use by way of a DPDT safety switch -- I already own [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-100-Amp-120-240-Volt-24-000-Watt-Non-Fused-General-Duty-Double-Throw-Safety-Switch-DT223URH-N/100151733).

However, the only circuit breaker that would be sized to protect the wires between the inlet and main panel (through the ATS and safety switch) would be the circuit breaker inside the generator.

Is that allowable by code? Or do I need to put in a hard-wired single-circuit breaker panel before the safety switch to protect the wires?

Comment: I suppose I could also replace the inlet with one that has an integrated circuit breaker like the Reliance PR50, in lieu of a separate single circuit breaker panel. But obviously I'd like to avoid spending the money on either one if I can avoid it and still remain code-legal.

Comment: Will the smaller generator start automatically?   I'm just confused of what you stand to gain.  Worst case inline fuse boxes are not that expensive and come with a free shutoff switch.  They are used in hot tubs etc.

Comment: @Harper No, it will not start automatically. The inline breaker panel is around $100 and while not expensive, its a cost I rather not spend for no reason.

Comment: $100 seems like a lot to me.  I just can't wrap my mind around how it is useful to have a *manual* generator on an *automatic* transfer switch.  Especially if it's a portable generator that is utterly incapable of having all the loads in the house slammed onto it suddenly. So you'll still have to shut all the breakers off, start the gen, cutover, switch loads on one at a time, not switch on certain big loads, that whole routine...

Comment: @Harper The automatic transfer switch supports load shedding, etc. Since this is a backup to the standby generator, I would like to be able to maintain the same load shedding capabilities if I have to switch to the backup. At 10 running kW/12 kW surge, my portable generator is plenty big enough to handle most of the loads in the house if properly managed by load-shedding. As opposed to right now, where using the standby generator _does_ require having to manage the various loads on my own. It makes sense to use the functionality of the ATS with the portable, manual generator.

Comment: The NEC requires standby generators that automatically transfer to be able to carry the full load of the building. It should be properly sized so there would be no load shedding. Having a switch that would defeat the automatic transfer doesn’t make sense. You might as well have a manual transfer switch then. A portable generator requires interactive load management, a standby generator is not supposed to require any intervention.

Comment: @ArchonOSX No one mentioned anything about a switch to defeat the automatic transfer. I merely want to be able to switch back to the inlet to use as a backup in case the automatic transfer switch fails. NEC does not require automatic transfers to carry the entire load of the building; it allows for automatically locking out circuits and/or dynamic load shedding. My goal is to leverage the dynamic load shedding supported by the ATS when using the portable generator.

Comment: You should post a diagram of your proposed wiring method. If you have a separate panel for the generator(s) then the ATS and standby generator have to be able to carry the entire load of that panel when it transfers. If that is what you mean by "dynamic load shedding" then that is approved by the NEC.The NEC calls it "load management" at 702.4 (B)(2)(b). You never mentioned that in your question. Hence, the reason for the wiring diagram as to how you plan to accomplish all of this.

Comment: @ArchonOSX I didn't discuss this in the original question because it isn't part of the original question. Rather than answering the original question, you're discussing something unrelated. However, yes, Dynamic Load Shedding is the Generac brand name for Load Management. There is no additional panel. It dynamically peels off larger circuits that are wired through special modules interactively to ensure that the generator's total capacity is not exceeded, which makes it comply with code.

Comment: It's a shame this never got a good answer, I think it's a good question.  If it's possible to connect a generator too big for said wires then they should certainly have a fixed breaker.  But if they are protected by the generator's breakers and a suitably *sized* inlet, perhaps code allows no fixed breakers.  Good question.  It's been a couple of years, what did you do?

Comment: Also I think people are confused by the question.  At the point you are using this you don't have a full ATS.  You have the backfeed protection and load shed components of an ATS combined with an MTS to switch input power.    No ATS at all.  And you have the feed wire from the generator to the MTS protected only by the generator's integrated breakers.  Is that ok?  That is the question.  I think actually that is the typical arrangement.

Comment: @jay613 I found a 50 amp generator inlet from Reliance that has an integral Square D breaker slot. That is one of the inputs to the safety switch, and the standby generator is the other input. The safety switch feeds the ATS. The AHJ thought it was acceptable and approved the permit.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer -- if you're still about, post that as an answer and I'll give you a +1 for it

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I am, and I just posted it! Ironically because of an unfortunate confluence of events we're just bringing this standby generator and ATS online now; the changeover to the new service feeding it will be happening on Jan 4!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [50 amp generator inlet from Reliance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PPCI1R2) that has an integral Square D breaker slot. That is one of the inputs to the safety switch, and the standby generator is the other input. The safety switch feeds the ATS. The AHJ thought it was acceptable and approved the permit.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the automatic interlock upstream of the interlocked panel you already have?

If that is your main panel you could side-grade it to a sub panel and put a main breaker upstream of the auto-switch.

Comment: The automatic transfer switch already will be upstream of the panel. It includes a 200A service rated main breaker. The goal here is to eliminate the interlock at the panel and instead bring the inlet in through the ATS as well.

Answer (score -1):

The transfer switch needs to be sized for the load.

this is code. If the panel that is being interrupted is 200 amp the ats has to be 200 a not just the size of the generator.

The ability to load shed is ok but the switch it self needs to be able to isolate the mains power. If the main service drop is 200a the switch will be 200a.

If the switch has load shedding capability the generator only has to be sized to the load. But the switch has to carry everything the panel is rated for it is isolating.